# c++ WebRequest with POST

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I currently use this command to do simple get transfer between my c++ application and my PHP web server.

```
WebRequest ^wrGETURL;
wrGETURL = WebRequest::Create(sURL);
Stream ^objStream = wrGETURL->GetResponse()->GetResponseStream();
```

But I would like to create a POST request with the `WebRequest` class is it possible?

Comment: That is not C++, that is C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Set the Method property of a RequestState instance linked to your WebRequest to "POST". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.net.webrequest.method.aspx